# How to uninstall Anaconda even without Anaconda Uninstall.exe?

Tags: python, anaconda

I had several issue with Jupyter and thought of uninstalling anaconda and reinstalling it. But when I uninstall, it says successfully uninstalled but anaconda is still there.

Answer (score -1):

To uninstall Anaconda open a terminal window and remove the entire anaconda install directory: `rm -rf ~/anaconda`. You may also edit `~/.bash_profile` and remove the anaconda directory from your `PATH` environment variable, and remove the hidden .condarc file and .conda and .continuum directories which may have been created in the home directory with `rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum`.

Further notes:
•Python3 installs may use a `~/anaconda3` dir instead of `~/anaconda`.
•You might also have a ~/.anaconda hidden directory that may be removed.
•Depending on how you installed, it is possible that the PATH is modified in one of your runcom files, and not in your shell profile. So, for example if you are using bash, be sure to check your `~/.bashrc` if you don't find the PATH modified in  `~/.bash_profile`.

You can go through directly https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-uninstall.html?highlight=uninstall

Comment: These instructions are for *nix systems, but OP appears to be on Windows.